# compare special characters like À with regular A

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring

In some languages there are letters like `À`, I saw that for table view sections the native iOS put `À` under the same section as `A`.
I want to do the same thing, I'm building my sections by comparing the first letter, so I need that `À` will be equal to A.
 I tried using `localizedCompare` but still I didn't got that those two are equal.

Is there a way to to this kind of compare? or to normalised `À` so it will be `A` ?

Comment: Look at the options for the NSString compare functions. It's all there in the NSString documentation.

Answer (score 2):

Don't convert or transform as per the other answers. First, try `-[NSString localizedStandardCompare:]`. If that doesn't do what you want, pass `NSDiacriticInsensitiveSearch` among the options to one of the `NSString` comparison methods (such as `-compare:options:range:locale:`). You may want to use additional options, too, such as `NSCaseInsensitiveSearch`.

Answer (score 0):

You can convert it first into regular alphabets and then compare.

```
NSString *originalStr = @"À béautiful day";
NSData *d = [originalStr dataUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding allowLossyConversion:YES];
NSString *converted = [[NSString alloc] initWithData:d encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a great article about `CFStringTransform` on NSHipser http://nshipster.com/cfstringtransform/

> Next, apply the kCFStringTransformStripCombiningMarks transform to remove any diacritics or accents.